# Why I obtain this PropertyReferenceException trying to implement this Spring Data JPA named query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am pretty new in **Spring Data JPA** and I am finding the following problem trying to implement this named query that have to join 2 table.

So I have the following situation, I have these 2 entity classes:

1) **Room** representing a room of an accomodation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_accomodation_fk", nullable = false)
    private Accomodation accomodation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_room_tipology_fk", nullable = false)
    private RoomTipology roomTipology;

    @Column(name = "room_number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "room_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "room_description")
    @Type(type="text")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "max_people")
    private Integer maxPeople;

    @Column(name = "is_enabled")
    private Boolean isEnabled;

    // CONSTRUCTOR, GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

As you can see this class contains this field:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_room_tipology_fk", nullable = false)
private RoomTipology roomTipology;
```

that link many **Room** instance to a **RoomTipology** instancce (is this reasoing correct?)

2) Then I have **RoomTipology** entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room_tipology")
public class RoomTipology implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "tipology_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "tipology_description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private Date timeStamp;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
    private List<Room> rooms;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
    private RoomRate roomRate;

    // CONSTRUCTOR, GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

Then I have this repository clas for the **RoomTipology** entity class, something like:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface RoomTipologyDAO extends JpaRepository<RoomTipology, Long> {

    RoomTipology findByRoomTipology_Room(Room room);

}
```

I wnt to retrieve the related **RoomTipology** instance starting from the **Room**.

So, as you can see, I have done:

```
RoomTipology findByRoomTipology_Room(Room room);
```

But doing in this way it can't work because when my application starts I obtain the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomTipologyDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property roomTipology found for type RoomTipology!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:732) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:103) [spring-boot-test-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84) [junit-rt.jar:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property roomTipology found for type RoomTipology!
```

So basically the error seems to depn by **No property roomTipology found for type RoomTipology!** because the **roomTipology** field is not into the **RoomTipology** entity class but it is into the **Room class**.

How can I solve this issue and correctly implement the named query method that dive a **Room** return the related **RoomTipology** into my **RoomTipologyDAO** repository class?

Comment: Have you tried just `RoomTipology findByRoom(Room room);`?

Comment: @AdamRosini in this way it can'ts work because into the RoomTipology entity class there is not a Room room field, infact using your suggestion I obtain th following error message at application startup: "org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property room found for type RoomTipology! Did you mean 'rooms'?". As you can see in the previous error message the RoomTipology class contain the List<Room> rooms. So I am thinking that maybe I can use this field to achieve my task...but I don't know how...

Comment: If you already have a `Room` reference, can you just say `room.getRoomTipology()`?